# Unable to update/Create post on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, web

I am attempting to update/create post on wordpress. However, I am always redirected to post.php stating: "It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching, or one of the links below, can help."

I have attempted the following:
- Checked Permalink Settings (Currently is by Post Name)
- Disabled all Plug ins
- Update Wordpress
- Enable Debug mode in wp-config (no debug logs captured)
- use a default theme (same error)

The site is showing perfectly, just having issues on making changes to post/page. I suspect that it is some permission issue

The website is http://stss.org.sg

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there a few accounts on your site? What's your role on the site? Answering these questions, you can help us identify your problem and solve it easier.

Comment: hi there, only 1 single use account (admin). I have noticed that the update works if and only if the embedded GoogleMap (Iframe) is removed. Is there any settings that are blocking it to be updated?

Comment: Can you please check by changing permalink structure to default one and check.?

Comment: tested on permalink. now the issues seems to occur only if there are iframes in the post/page...

Comment: Can you show a sample iframe here ?

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3988.5643246156264!2d103.80391051529195!3d1.4365490989523264!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31da139c4f27c8df%3A0x92099a6642296f04!2sSingapore+737855!5e0!3m2!1sen!2ssg!4v1494133438516" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>, basically, even with just a empty iframe tag, the update will fail..

Comment: No idea. I suspect some permission issue in db.

Comment: Can you please add this code to your function.php file and check

function my_deregister_scripts(){
 wp_deregister_script( 'wp-embed' );
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_deregister_scripts' );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143590/discussion-between-ashkar-and-kenau89).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new user account with administration role! Then delete the previous user and use the new user account! Hope that will help!

Comment: hi, thks for the advice. problem persist when a post has embedded iframes for googlemap...

Comment: Thanks! I'm happy to help you! <3